# Plugin controller actions

Tags: php, cakephp

I am working on a plugin and I am having a small issue with adding actions to the plugins main controller.

For example I have this plugin controller (one_page_app_controller), what I am attempting to do is have actions with in this controller. So that if I path to www.site.com/one_page/ the index action is called. At this point, I am not even sure if this is possible.

This is the controller I am currently working with. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

class OnePageAppController extends AppController {

function index()
{

}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can access the plugin at /:plugin/:controller/:action. So you need to add the plugin name in there (or the folder name of the plugin)

Edit: you can set the default action `Router::connect('/plugin_name/', array('plugin'=>'plugin_name','controller' => 'blah', 'action' => 'blah'));`

Comment: That is currently what I am doing, however what if I wanted to do just www.site.com/plugin_name/ and use actions in the plugin app controller? Is this even possible?

Comment: you can set the routes for the plugin, I'll update my answer.